# Get attachments for posts that belongs to a specific category

Tags: posts, categories, attachments, get-posts, images

I am trying to get images which are used by a post belonging to the specific category. For example if I have plants, mushrooms and animals as post categories, I only need to retrieve images that are attached to posts of those categories. All images don't have to belong to the same post, it would even be better if they are random. Can it be done?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_category' => 'plants',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 9,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_parent' => 'null'
    );
$attachments = get_posts($args);
foreach ($attachments as $post) :
    ?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I would go for a more stable approach and use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/

Comment: Thank you Zlatev, yeah this is much better solution. I have tried a few plugins and I think this one is best for me if anyone is searching the same https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-multiple-images/